# Entity Framework multiple mapping to same table DB first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have an issue with an Entity Framework from DB model.

My issue is down to the fact that one of my models has a multiple references to one table.

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> PrimaryEngId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> AssignedDevloperId { get; set; }

    public virtual Engineer Engineer { get; set; }
    public virtual Engineer Engineer1 { get; set; }
}
```

In my model the columns are mapped respectively, however when a colleague builds the model from the same database the two are reversed.

I believe the issue is that the first mapping to in was the `primaryEngId`
and the Db constraint is called `FK_Customer_Engineer`.

And the assigned developer id was added subsequently and the DB constraint is called `FK_Customer_Devloper`

So alphabetically `Developer` come before `Engineer` and Entity Framework now maps them the other way round.

My code references the `Engineer` in quite a lot of places which now won't work

Is there any way out of this?

Many thanks

Ian

Answer (score 2):

You have to add missing ForeignKey attributes on foreign keys for those two navigation properties:

```
[ForeignKey("Primary")]
public int? PrimaryEngId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Assigned")]    
public int? AssignedDevloperId { get; set; }

public virtual Engineer Primary { get; set; }

public virtual Engineer Assigned { get; set; }
```

*NOTE*: Also don't use generic names for navigation properties with EF. In the nutshell one of the best things EF gives you is that you can say:

```
@myCustomer.Assigned.Name
```

etc in the view, and you are totally screwing it up with names like Engineer and Engineer1.

*NOTE2*: Keep `Nullable<int>` to code generation. `int?` is a lot more readable.

*NOTE3*: Use VS refactoring to rename properties `Engineer` and `Engineer1` to what they should be ( `PrimaryEngineer` and `AssignedEningeer` etc). After that add `ForeignKey` attributes to your model. That should be enough. However, any future changes that you are doing has to be done in the Code and not in db.

**IF** on the other hand you are constantly regenerating entities and context code from database, make sure that all your foreign keys has meaningful names, as EF will use them to generate name.(ie it is not named `Engineer1` out of blue) Rename those foreign keys to reflect what logical relationship is. Ie you most likely have the following foreign keys in db:

```
 FK_Customer_Engineer

 FK_Customer_Engineer1
```

You need to rename them to

```
 FK_Customer_PrimaryEngineer

 FK_Customer_AssignedEngineer
```

*Update*: you can have different column name and property name like so:

```
[Column("PrimaryEngId")]
[ForeignKey("Primary")]
public int? PrimaryID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sadly when I took over as the project Lead the Model is being developed using the DB first system. so the DB code for all this is generated by entity Framework, is there issues with changing the code in the DB first system?

Comment: Depends on where you are planing to do changes to the schema - in the code or in the schema. If you need to regenerate classess from db every tme it does not make much sense to change it, as you will end up doing it every time. If you are making any future change in the code and run ef-migration on db, you can update those, because as far as EF is concerned of only Foreign Key name, which is by default is equal to property name, but can be overriden with attribute, if you want your code to follow your code conventions /style guides etc.